# how can i tell select() in dplyr that the string it is seeing is a column name in a data frame

Tags: r

I tried searching but didn't find an answer to this question.

I'm trying to use the select statement in dplyr but am having problems when I try to send it strings. My question is, how do i tell select() that the string that it is seeing is a column name in the data frame?

e.g. this works fine

```
select(df.main.scaled, var1, var3)
select(df.main.scaled, var2, var4)
```

but this does not work:

```
select(df.main.scaled, names.gens[i,1], names.gens[i,2])
```

where

```
> names.genx <- c("var1","var2")
> names.geny <- c("var3","var4")
> names.gens <- cbind(names.genx, names.geny)
> names.gens
     names.genx names.geny
[1,] "var1"     "var3"    
[2,] "var2"     "var4"
```

To be clear, all the strings in names.gens are column names in the data frame.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't currently. In a future version you'll be able to do something like `select(.vars = names.gens[i, ])`

Comment: This works but does not use select: `nms <- c("disp", "cyl"); mtcars %.% "["(nms)`

Comment: There is a new answer to this by slizb that is awesome :)

Comment: For people who want to select a column and be able to rename it you can use `df %>% select(new.name = glue::glue_collapse(column.variable)`

Answer (score -6, accepted):

I figured it out through trial and error. If anybody is curious, did something like this:

```
lapply(names.gens, as.name)
select(df.main.scaled, eval(names.gens[[i]]), eval(names.gens[[i+someindex]]))
```

Comment: If you had to do this, rather than just using `df.main.scaled[, names.gen[i, ])`, `get()` would be better than `eval()` + `as.name()`

Answer (score 66):

In more recent versions of dplyr, this is possible in `select` with `one_of`, as in

```
my_cols <- c('mpg', 'disp')
mtcars %>% select(one_of(my_cols))
```

Answer (score 36):

Select seems to work with the column indexes (dplyr 0.2), so just match your desired names to their index and use them to select the columns.

```
myCols <- c("mpg","disp")
colNums <- match(myCols,names(mtcars))
mtcars %>% select(colNums)
```

Comment: Nice answer. To make this into one line without repeating dataset names: 
    `mtcars %>% select(match(myCols,names(.)))`

Comment: The way to do this in more recent versions of dplyr  is with `one_of`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 15):

You can use `get()` to get the object named by the string in the current environment. So:

```
R> iris %>% select(Species, Petal.Length) %>% head(3)
  Species Petal.Length
1  setosa          1.4
2  setosa          1.4
3  setosa          1.3
R> iris %>% select('Species', 'Petal.Length') %>% head(3)
Error in abs(ind[ind < 0]) : 
  non-numeric argument to mathematical function     
R> iris %>% select(get('Species'), get('Petal.Length')) %>% head(3)
  Species Petal.Length
1  setosa          1.4
2  setosa          1.4
3  setosa          1.3
R> s <- 'Species'
R> p <- 'Petal.Length'
R> iris %>% select(get(s), get(p)) %>% head(3)
  Species Petal.Length
1  setosa          1.4
2  setosa          1.4
3  setosa          1.3
```

Comment: Is there a way to use this with a vector of column names? I.e., `cols <- c('Species', 'Petal.Length')`

Answer (score 13):

[Edit - some of the below is now out of date with the release of dplyr 0.7 - see [here](https://blog.rstudio.com/2017/06/13/dplyr-0-7-0/)]

The question is about the difference between standard evaluation and non standard evaluation.

tl;dnr:  You can use the 'standard evaluation' counterpart of `dplyr::select`, which is `dplyr::select_` .

This allows you to provide column names as variables which contain strings:

`dplyr::select_(df.main.scaled, names.gens[i,1], names.gens[i,2])`

Here is lots more detail that tries to explain how this works:

## Non standard evaluation and the select function in dplyr

Non-standard evaluation is the evaluation of code in non-standard ways.  Often, this means capturing expressions before they are evaluated, and evaluating them in a different environment (context/scope) to normal.  When you provide `dplyr::select` with column names without quotation marks, `dplyr` is using non-standard evaluation to interpret them as columns.

### Examples of use of dplyr::select

Supposing we have the following data frame:

```
df <- tibble::data_frame(a = 1:5, b = 6:10, c = 11:15, d = 16:20)
```

A simple example of the select statement is as follows:

```
r <- dplyr::select(df, a, b)
```

This is an example of NSE because a and b are not variables that exist in the global environment.  Instead of searching for a and b in the global namespace, `dplyr::select` directs R to search for the variables a and b in the context of dataframe `df`.  You can think of the environment a bit like a list, and a and b as keys.  So the following is a bit like telling R to lookup `df$a` and `df$b`

Function arguments in R are [promises](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Promise-objects) which are not evaluated immediately.  They can be captured as expressions and then run in a different environment.

This is fine if we know we want to select the columns `a` and `b` in advance.  But what if these columns are unknown in advance, and are held in a variable.

```
columns_to_select <- c("a", "b")
```

The following does not work:

```
 dplyr::select(df, columns_to_select)
```

This error is telling us that there is no column called 'columns_to_select' in the dataframe.  The argument `columns_to_select` has been evaluated in the context of the dataframe, so R has tried to do something like `df$columns_to_select`, and found that the column does not exist.

How do we fix this?

Tidyverse functions always provide an ['escape hatch'](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#substitute) that allow you to get around this limitation.   The [dplyr vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html) says 'Every function in dplyr that uses NSE also has a version that uses SE. The name of the SE version is always the NSE name with an _ on the end.'

What does this mean?

We might try the following, but we find it does not work:

```
# Does not work
r <-dplyr::select_(df, columns_to_select)
```

As opposed to capturing the argument `columns_to_select` to the select_ function and interpreting it as a column name, `columns_to_select` is evaluated in a standard way, resolving to `c("a", "b")`.

That's what we want, except that each argument to `select_` is a single column, and we've just provided a character vector of length two to represent a single column.

The above code therefore returns a tibble with a single column, a, which is not what we wanted.  (Only the first element - `"a"` in the character vector is used, everything else is ignored).

One solution to this problem is as follows, but it assumes that `columns_to_select` contains exactly two elements:

```
col1 <- columns_to_select[1]
col2 <- columns_to_select[2]
r <- dplyr::select_(df,col1, col2)
```

How do we generalise this to the case where `columns_to_select` may have an arbitrary number of elements?

The solution is to use the optional `.dots` argument.

```
 dplyr::select_(df, .dots=columns_to_select)
```

This bears some explanation

In R, the [`...` construct](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Dot_002ddot_002ddot) allows the creation of functions with a variable (arbitrary) number of arguments.  The `...` is available *within* the function, and allows the function body to access all of the arguments.  See also [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-three-dots-ellipsis/).

A very simple example is as follows:

```
addition <- function(...) {
  args <- list(...)
  sum(unlist(args))
}
r <- addition(1,2,3)
```

However, this doesn't immediately help us here.  It's actually already implemented in the `select_` function and merely enables us to provide an arbitrary number of column names as arguments, e.g. `select_(df, "a", "b", "c", "d")`.

What we need is a mechanism that is similar to `...`, but allows us to pass something like `...` *into* the function as a single argument.  This is exactly what `.dots` does.

Note that `.dots` is not provided by `select`, because this is designed to be used interactively.

Answer (score 9):

I ran across this and I thought I should mention that this has been solved in newer versions of dplyr.

```
myTest = data_frame(
  var1 = 1, 
  var2 = 2,
  var3 = 3,
  var4 = 4)

i = 1

myTest %>%
  select_(.dots = 
     c(names.gens[i,1], names.gens[i,2]) %>% unname)
```

Answer (score 6):

For strings you can do

```
my_cols <- c("mpg", "disp")
mtcars %>% select(!!!my_cols)
```

although, I think it would probably be better practice to avoid strings and do

```
my_cols <- quos(mpg, disp)
mtcars %>% select(!!!my_cols)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a workaround in dplyr 0.1.2 using regular expressions and matches (see hadley's comment below for information on direct support in future versions). A regular expression such as `^(x1|x2|x3)$` matches exact variables names so we just have to construct such an expression from a vector with variables names. Here is the code

```
# load libraries
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
# create data.frame
df = data.frame(
    x = rep(0,5),
    y = 1,
    var = 2,
    another_var = 5,
    var.4 = 6
)
# function to construct reg exp from vector with variable names
varlist = function(x) {
    x = str_c('^(',paste(x, collapse='|'),')$')
    x = str_replace_all(x,'\\.','\\\\.')
    return(x)
}
# select variables based on vector of variable names
vars = c('y','another_var','var.4')
df %>%
    select(matches(varlist(vars)))
```