# r dplyr transmute_ string input error

Tags: r, dplyr

Given a dataframe and a string containing the operation to perform on the columns:

```
myDF <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(1,2,3,4),c(1,2,3,4),c(1,2,3,4)))
myString <- 'Added = V1 + V2'
```

Calling 'transmute_()' will give me the desired output:

```
transmute_(myDF,myString)
```

Output:

```
  Added = V1 + V2
1               2
2               4
3               6
4               8
```

Great so far! But if I immediately repeat the same 'transmute_()' function I get an error.

```
transmute_(myDF,myString)
Error: invalid (do_set) left-hand side to assignment
```

Changing the input string's column names still gives the same error and storing the same string in a different variable does so too. However, if I change the new column name, it works again for the first time, followed by error (see examples for each below).

I'm not sure why that is. It seems like a temporary version of the output is stored somewhere and the error is a reaction to this but I've never encountered anything like this before. Any help understanding it and going around it (besides the obvious re-naming of the new column) would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
myString <- 'Added = V1 + V3'
transmute_(myDF,myString)
Error: invalid (do_set) left-hand side to assignment

myString2 <- 'Added = V1 + V3'
transmute_(myDF,myString2)
Error: invalid (do_set) left-hand side to assignment

myString2 <- 'Added_2 = V1 + V3'
transmute_(myDF,myString2)
  Added_2 = V1 + V3
1                 2
2                 4
3                 6
4                 8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mutate_` has the same issue, but looking at the code it is because transmute_ does a call to mutate_. It is a not so much a bug in dplyr, but there is an issue raised for this on the dplyr github page. See [github issue 315](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/315).

After you run `transmute_(myDF,myString)` you can see that `Added` is available in the base environment. Just type it (or `base::Added`) and you will see the object and the values that have been created. This causes an issue when you call your line of code again.

For more details read the comments on the [github issue 315](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/315) by Romain Francois and Hadley Wickham

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you response @phiver! I'm posting this as an alternative answer for now and will leave the question open for a bit longer to see if anyone has a nicer solution to this...
It really seems like this is somewhat of a dead end. Another way of seeing that `Added` is sitting in the base is by using the 'pryr' package:

```
library(pryr)
where(Added) 
<environment: base>
```

Unfortunately it seems like the base can't be edited:

```
rm('Added',inherits = TRUE)
Error in rm('Added',inherits = TRUE)
cannot remove bindings from a locked environment
```

At this point I feel it would be too complicated to go further into this. My ultimate goal was to perform an operation on a specific number of coumns, where the column names can change from case to case. Using strings (and therefore the `transmute_()` function) seemed to make most sense. However, here's an alternative approach (idea from [how can i tell select() in dplyr that the string it is seeing is a column name in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028937/how-can-i-tell-select-in-dplyr-that-the-string-it-is-seeing-is-a-column-name-i)):

```
colsOfInterest <- c('V1','V2')
colPosInDF <- match(colsOfInterest , names(myDF))
reduced_myDF <- select(myDF,colPosInDF)
desired_DF <- as.data.frame(rowSums(reduced_myDF))
```

Not very nice but it does the job. If anyone has a cleaner workaround please feel free to share!